# Replace double backslash with single backslash in bytestring

Tags: python-3.x, hana, backslash

I've stored my data: `b'\xa2ac\xa0av\xf6' of <class 'bytes'>` in SAP HANA but when I query it using pyHDB, the result escapes the backslashes as such: `b'\\xa2ac\\xa0av\\xf6' <class 'bytes'>`.

How do I keep the data type as bytes but remove the double backslashes? I've looked at turning it into a string and replacing the backslashes then converting it back into bytes but once I convert it back to bytes the double backslashes are there again. I am using Python3. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works, but I'm not sure if it is very elegant.

```
import ast

def remove_double_backslashes(b):
    return ast.literal_eval(str(b).replace('\\\\', '\\'))
```

In case you are using an older Python version than 3.2, you would probably need to replace `ast.literal_eval` with `eval`. That built-in function can *sometimes* be dangerous, however I as an amateur programmer can't think why `eval(str(b))`, where `b` is a bytes object, could do any harm. You could even verify that `b` is a bytes object with `assert type(b) == bytes`.

(By the way, I don't know what SAP HANA or pyHDB are, but I think I still answered the question)

**EDIT/NOTE**:

Even `assert type(b) == bytes` won't prevent harm if someone decides to redefine the name `bytes` to mean something else, like so:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.oro = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "open('file', 'wb')" # DON'T DO THIS...

bytes = Foo # DON'T DO THIS...
```